# Handling exception resulting from transaction timeout when using Spring / Hibernate / Postgres

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I'm attempting to provide a useful error message to users of a system where some queries may take a long time to execute. I've set a transaction timeout using Spring using `@Transactional(timeout = 5)`.

This works as expected, but the caller of the annotated method receives a `JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet` exception (caused by `GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet`, in turn caused by `PSQLException: ERROR: canceling statement due to user request`).

As far as I can tell, the exception is a result of a statement being cancelled by Hibernate and the JDBC driver once the timeout has been exceeded.

Is there any way I can determine that the exception was a result of the transaction timeout being exceeded so that I can provide an error message to the user about why their query failed?

The application is using Spring framework 4.2.9, Hibernate 4.3.11, and Postgres JDBC driver 9.4.1209. I realise these are quite old. If newer versions make handling this situation easier I would be interested to know.

Answer (score 0):

How about you check the exception message of the cause of the cause against some regex pattern or just checking if the message contains the string like this?

```
exception.getCause().getCause().getMessage().equals("ERROR: canceling statement due to user request")
```